# Can I seal off these ceiling cavities in my basement from rodent pest access and/or remove the old, soiled insulation inside to stop smells?

Tags: insulation, basement, pest-control, smell, mice

Part of our kitchen/dining room extends into our back yard where there's no basement underneath. Perhaps it was an addition at some point (it's a 1940s house) but down in the 'unfinished' side of the basement you can see into the cavity beneath this part of the kitchen where the ceiling joists run for probably a further ~7 feet:

[image: Here's how it looks fron the basement]

These cavities between the joists have been stuffed full of fibreglass insulation but we believe mice and rats have been using this as an access route to our basement (and possibly as a home, based on the musty/urine kind of smells present around there). We're keen to A) stop pests being able to enter our basement via these holes, and B) get rid of the soiled insulation smell down there.

We've taken several measures to limit rodent access from the outside, though we still haven't been able to find any obvious routes in (under house siding or through a crack in our concrete foundation, for example), and these cavities are so small there's no real way to crawl in there to inspect for access holes, dead mice etc.

I'm just wondering - could/should we completely seal up these ceiling cavities with either wire mesh or insulation foam boards (or a combination of both) in order to limit their access/stop the smell from the old rotten insulation, or could we even totally remove the old, soiled insulation and then seal it up?

Here are my ideas/concerns that I'd like some opinions on:

- If we just block up the holes, pests might still get into these spaces under the floorboards from somewhere on the outside of our house and eventually chew their way through/die in the floors/cause other problems
- If we block off airflow to the insulation then it could just soak up moisture and become a breeding ground for mould or rot away our floorboards/joists, though there is seemingly an old air vent on the wall outside the house - perhaps this was installed to allow the insulation to dry off?
- If we pull out all the old, soiled insulation, it might make our kitchen floor way less insulated and will leach our heat energy back into the foundation of the house; that's not a huge concern but thought it worth mentioning in case it should be...
- We've already sealed all of our basement windows so fresh airflow is probably already pretty limited down there, but we have a dehumidifier in the 'finished' side of the basement and it generally stays around 50%

I would love it if I could just block up these cavities, and if it would stop the smell and I could just forget that old insulation is even down there then great, but my gut feeling is that the old, soiled insulation probably needs to come out (not looking forward to that job ) but then I'm unsure whether to just re-fill it with new insulation for the pests to just start soiling again, or to forget about it and just block off the basement side holes with foam boards. Would appreciate some input.